# Inject array of columns to COUNT in SELECT MSSQL - dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have prepared a sting of columns which can be added (hence the need for the dynamic query.

I have `@cols` which can be printed with an output like `"Color","Size","Width"`

I then have a `SELECT/COUNT` statement which needs to look like as follows...

```
SELECT
   Product_code,
   count(distinct [Color]),
   count(distinct [Size]),
   count(distinct [Width])
FROM.....
```

I need of the columns that I have in my string of columns to be counted with distinct..

Also would be even better if I could add a AS with the name of each of these in here too!

Many help is much appreciated - my SQL are OK but the dynamic bit turns me blue!

Cheers.

Comment: I think you are not willing to type, right?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand?

Comment: If you would like to do it dynamically, do it in your host language. Better yet, select them all from SQL: assuming that all the appropriate indexes are in place, the overhead should be small, - and then display only the ones that have been requested.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight really needs to kept in SQL to make it faster rather than throwing further SQL calls and additional process on my webserver - It can be achieved!

Comment: @MattTheNinja There's no extra calls required, and the time difference between selecting one `count(distinct)` vs. ten `count(distinct)`s should be too tiny to notice, because the results would be retrieved straight from the indexes.

Comment: So, is `@cols` a table valued parameter or a `(N)VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your comma seperated list to a table first. [See this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx)
Assuming that table name to be `ListOfColumns`

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR( 1000 ) = '';

SELECT @Query+=@Query + ', COUNT(DISTINCT ' + COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ' + COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
       INNER JOIN ListOfColumns d ON c.COLUMN_NAME = d.ColName
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable';

SET @Query = 'SELECT ' + STUFF( @query,1,3,'' ) + ' FROM Tbl';

EXEC ( @Query );
```

Comment: Can I do a `FROM` statement on my string?

Comment: You may need to create mapping table if you are looking for fancy name to be displayed directly in report